# Яке слово коректно вживати: посилання чи покликання під час написання курсової/дипломної?

Tags: правопис, наголос, розмовна-українська

Моя наукова керівниця завжди говорить "покликАння". Я розумію, що вона має на увазі, але чи це коректно?

Знайшла лише "поклИкання", але не "покликАння".

> Посилання (англ. reference), також поклик — посилання у паперових і електронних документах — уривок, витяг з якого-небудь твору, на який
> посилаються у викладі, з точною назвою джерела й вказівкою на
> відповідну сторінку. Іноді те саме, що виноска[1]. Останнім часом
> паралельно почали вживати термін — покликання.
>
> **ПОКЛИ́КАННЯ, я, сер.**
>
> 1. Внутрішній потяг, здатність, схильність до певної справи, професії. Писала Галя й зять до «коханих родичів», що Славко не поробив ніяких
>    іспитів,.. що він не думає братися за науку, бо не має до того
>    покликання (Лесь Мартович, Тв., 1954, 424); Після перших драматичних
>    спроб Панас Мирний звертається до прози, де знаходить своє справжнє
>    покликання (Життя і творчість Т. Г. Шевченка, 1959, 631); Покликання
>    до складання пісень у Шевченка було настільки великим, що
>    народнопісенні образи, мотиви, які завжди роїлися в його голові, часто
>    виливались у формі імпровізації (Народна творчість та етнографія, 2,
>    1964, 38).
> 2. Призначення. Велике покликання матері народити людину, але найвеличніше — народити й виховати не вовка, а друга, не хижака, а
>    брата (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 335); Розуміла [Л. Українка]
>    покликання своє: поезією-зброєю служити боротьбі за соціальне і
>    національне визволення народу (Максим Рильський, III, 1956, 281).
>    Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 7, 1976. — Стор. 30.

Comment: Коли про іменкову ланку, то є таке [запитання](/questions/1217/)

Comment: перепрошую, а що таке *іменкова ланка*?

Comment: [Говіркове](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mJcpvbLuVsjiEpvySqnKbKv0flhOoDvL/) Site Link

Comment: конкретизувала питаня

Comment: @Orti, перепрошую, але все ж не розумію суті вашого запитання: воно про різницю між словами *покликання* та *посилання*, чи про те, яким словом позначити дію, коли ви цитуєте чиюсь працю у тексті курсової, чи про спосіб цитування (взаказти Автора/ів та назву, навести веб-адресу, назву книги, тощо)?

Answer (score 2):

Я не можу дати однозначної відповіді.

***Поси́лання*** походить від дієслова *посила́тися*; [фрагмент відповідної статті зі «Словника української мови в 11 томах»](http://sum.in.ua/s/posylatysja):

> **ПОСИЛА́ТИСЯ**, аюся, аєшся, *недок[онане]*, **ПОСЛА́ТИСЯ**, пошлюся, пошлешся, *доконане*.
>
> 1. Вказувати на кого-небудь як на свідка або авторитетну особу, називати щось як аргумент для підтвердження своїх слів, виправдання дій і т. ін. <…>
>      // Для обґрунтування своїх дій або вчинків називати причину, що їх викликала. <…>
>      // Повідомляти що-небудь (факти, цифри і т. ін.) для підкріплення своєї думки. <…>
>      // На доказ правомірності своїх міркувань наводити або згадувати відповідні висловлювання видатних теоретиків, учених, письменників і т. ін. <…>
> 2. <…>

***Поклика́ння*** походить від дієслова *поклика́тися*; [фрагмент відповідної статті зі «Словника української мови в 11 томах»](http://sum.in.ua/s/poklykatysja):

> **ПОКЛИКА́ТИСЯ**, а́юся, а́єшся, *недок[онане]*, **ПОКЛИ́КАТИСЯ**, и́чуся, и́чешся, *док[онане]*. Вказувати на кого-, що-небудь для підтвердження або виправдання чогось; наводити що-небудь як доказ; посилатися. <…>

*Посила́ння* проти *поклика́ння*:

- *Посила́ння* наразі, наскільки я можу судити, вживається частіше.
- І *посила́ння*, і *поклика́ння* присутні в словниках. Хоча *поклика́ння* відсутнє в деяких зі словників, де наявне *посила́ння* (наприклад, «Словник української мови» в 11 томах і «Словники України on-line» містять лише *покли́кання* в іншому значенні, але не *поклика́ння*), але воно теж міститься в словниках під егідою НАНУ з потрібним значенням:

  - «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» О. Кочерги і Є. Мейнаровича (2010) містить *поклика́ння* у відповідному значенні:

    > **citation** 1. цитува́ння//‌зацитува́ння (of – когось/чогось); [поклика́ння](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=4&highlight=on), посила́ння (of – на) 2. цита́та, зга́дка || цита́тний
    >
    > ---
    >
    > **[поклика́ння//‌покли́кання](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&dicts=5&highlight=on)** 1. reference (to) 2. (цитування) citation (of)
  - «Словник української мови» в 20 томах наразі ще не опублікував у вільний доступ томів на літеру *п-*, але вже містить *покликання* у потрібному значенні у визначеннях і цитатах до інших слів:

    > [АЛЮ́ЗІЯ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=154222&page=40), ї, ж[іночий рід], літ[ературознавство]. Стилістичний засіб, який полягає у використанні **покликання** на реальний загальновідомий політичний, історичний або літературний факт. <…>
    >
    > ---
    >
    > [ІНКРЕМЕНТУВА́ТИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1230&wordid=217547), у́ю, у́єш, *недок[онане] і док[онане]*, що, *спец[іальне слово]*. Здійснювати інкремент. *Якщо виконуваний двійковий файл належить до модульного домену виконання, то необхідно інкрементувати лічильник **покликань*** (з наук. літ.); <…>; *Отримати об'єкт у комп'ютерне оперування можна, якщо надіслати йому відповідне повідомлення, що інкрементує лічильник **покликань*** (із журн.).
- <sub>Значення слова *посила́ння* не залежить від наголосу, тому, на відміну від слова *поклика́ння* (що його можна прочитати як *покли́кання* — «внутрішній потяг, здатність, схильність; призначення»), це слово не вийде прочитати неправильно у друкованому тексті — але це не є вагомим критерієм.</sub>
- Деякі мовознавці, зокрема Тетяна Івасишина [у журналі «Українська мова» № 1 від 2010](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/37694/28-Ivasyshyna.pdf) і Ганна Арсенич-Баран (завкафедри філологічних дисциплін та методики їх викладання у Чернігівському обласному інституті післядипломної педагогічної освіти ім. К. Д. Ушинського
  і голова Чернігівської обласної організації Національної спілки письменників України) [у фейсбук-групі «Плекайте мову»](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1920959421528930/permalink/1956691507955721/) наполягають на вживанні саме слова *поклика́ння* — хоча їхня аргументація мені незрозуміла. Те ж саме рекомендують деякі інші джерела на зразок [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/) — але зовсім без аргументації.

Отже, здається, обидва слова є прийнятними.